# why chrome-dev-tools can't reflect 'this' correctly in a promise?

Tags: webpack, google-chrome-devtools, es6-promise, source-maps

I use `webpack` to compile my project, and then I found `this` will be compiled to `_this2` if there is a promise.

And the problem is that when I take a breakpoint in the promise, `this` will always be `undefined` in chrome-dev-tools.

Is it a bug? Is it difficult for Chromium develop team to resolve this?

Now, the source code:

[image]

the compiled code by `webpack`:

[image]

because there is a source-map, chrome will display the source code for me, and `this` outside the promise will be correctly inspected.

[image]

but, `this` inside the promise will be `undefined`

[image]

Answer (score 2):

As you point out when compiling the code to `es5` the resulting code uses the `_this` trick to capture this from the declaring context. The problem is that source maps are essentially just text maps, mapping a piece of the compiled code back to the source code. This means Chrome (or any other current debugger) will have no way of guessing that `this` that is under the cursor has a different meaning in the source code.

A simple way to get around this is to add a watch for `_this` (or `this_2` in your case) which will show you the captured this.

Comment: It seems like the dev tools need some kind of option to collapse captured scope, especially when `this` is `undefined`